# Converting a .txt with data on multiple lines to a .csv

Tags: python, csv, grouping

I'm trying to turn data from a `.txt` file into a `.csv` file using Python. My `.txt` file is currently formatted kind of like this:

```
www.thing.com
Thing
2010
linkedin.com/company/thing
www.hello.com
Hello
1999
linkedin.com/company/hello
...
```

I want a program that will read through the 4 lines about 'Thing', and make that into a row. Then, it will read the 4 lines about 'Hello', and make that into a row, with each item being in the same column as the row about 'Thing'.

```
"www.thing.com,Thing,2010,linkedin.com/company/thing"
"www.hello.com,Hello,1999,linkedin.com/company/hello"
...
```

Here's what I have so far (which is not a lot):

```
import csv

text_file = open("document.txt", "r")

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as mycsv:
    filewriter = csv.writer(mycsv)

    mycsv.writerow(["company", "name", "date", "linkedin"])

    for line in text_file:
        URL = line
        line = next(text_file)
        name = line
        line = next(text_file)
        date = line
        line = next(text_file)
        LinkedIn = line
        line = next(text_file)
        mycsv.writerow(URL, name, date, LinkedIn)
```

Most I've looked up so far already has the `.txt` document formatted with each row in only one line, but my `.txt` has one row of data in multiple lines.

How would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to solve your issue:

```
def group_data(table, n=4):
    # Group your table's data by n elements
    yield from [table[k: k + n] for k in range(0, len(table), n)]


def write_csv(file_name, data):
    with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
        # Loop over your grouped data
        for elm in data:
            # Write the grouped elemenets into a file
            f.write(','.join(k for k in elm) + '\n')



a = '''www.thing.com
Thing
2010
linkedin.com/company/thing
www.hello.com
Hello
1999
linkedin.com/company/hello'''

data = [elm for elm in a.split('\n')]
grouped = group_data(data)
write_csv('csv_file.csv', grouped)
```

Output:

```
www.thing.com,Thing,2010,linkedin.com/company/thing
www.hello.com,Hello,1999,linkedin.com/company/hello
```

**NB:** If your data cannot be grouped by a fixed number, then you should think about a new algorithm to have your desired output. Or, you can see if there is a repeated pattern you can use to make the grouping happen. Otherwise, this current code will work with your current text snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the input file by 4 lines by zipping the input file iterator for 4 times:

```
from itertools import repeat
csv.writer(mycsv).writerows([[i.rstrip() for i in r] for r in zip(*repeat(text_file, 4))])
```

Comment: This answer would be so much better if you didn't cram the crucial part `zip(*repeat(...))` into a single line along with everything else and added an explanation of how the elements `zip`, `repeat`, `*` worked together to read chunks of lines at a time from a file. As far as I can tell, this is all very non-trivial stuff that probably isn't going to help anybody who isn't already an expert in Python.